# wp-login gives 404 error, but wp-admin is working fine

Tags: login

/wp-admin it is working, but if I type /wp-login gives 404 error, any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`/wp-login` does not work for me either. Try `/wp-login.php`